# Could not connect Debugger with react-native app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to add debugger with react native android, But it always stuck on white screen and did not show anything. After 3 to 5 mint it shows the following message on android:-
[image: Error shows on android mobile screen :]

and on my visual studio code debugger console it shows:-
[image: Debbuger Console shows]

and here is my launch.json file:-

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Attach to packager",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
        "type": "reactnative",
        "request": "attach",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
    },
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
        "url": "http://localhost:8080",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug JS remotely it is necessary that both the mobile and the laptop to be in the same network then find the ip address of your laptop and then use the following commands

- adb shell input keyevent 82
- click in debug host option and enter your ip address there with port like that (e.g 192.168.110.2:8081)

Comment: When i install app normally, it works normally,but with debugger it hangs on starting with white screen..

Comment: is your device and laptop on the same network using the same internet ?

Comment: No, But it works few days ago. I think after installing realm this error occur. It could be.